# In mysql where clause bigint showing unexpected result

Tags: mysql

Hope you all are doing well.

Today morning I was writing some sql query and I found a situation where I need your suggestion on that so here is the situation:

I've a table in mysql called `users` it has `id` column which is `bigint`
now when I'm trying to extract data with a query like :

`select * from users where id = 123`
in this case it'll show the result for user `123`

now the situation here is if I run the same query like: 
`select * from users where id = 123b`
now the issue here is it is still giving me the data for user `123`

need your suggestion guys on the same, I did some R&D on the same but didn't found much usefull.

Thank you

Comment: What would you expect the result to be? If `id` is an int, surely there is no real user with the id "123b"

Comment: *now the situation here is if I run the same query like:
`select * from users where id = 123b`
now the issue here is it is still giving me the data for user 123* I don't believe you. You **must** receive error message "Unknown column name '123b'."

Comment: I think the OP is using some kind of prepared statement (notice the `mysqli` tag?), therefore the raw SQL query being sent is something like ```select * from users where id = '123b' ```

Comment: The problem here comes because when mysql compares string with int, mysql will cast the string to int (`123b` casted into int becomes `123`), see example here: https://gist.github.com/brianr/4208061 also you can do simple query like `SELECT 123 = '123b' ` and the result will be `1` (which is `true`)

Comment: @Mureinik there should be 0 if I put count(*) because there is no user with id 123b

Comment: @Akina you are right if you put a quote like `id = '123b'` it will not give you any error instead of that it will show you the result for record `123` but if you query like `id = 123b` then it will give you the error "unknown column name '123b'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with **mysqli** which means you are using **PHP** to build your query. If you pass the string `123b` as an integer, PHP will keep the leading digits:

```php
var_dump((int)'123b');
# output: int(123)
```

MySQL then execute your query with this well formed integer `123`.

If you execute a raw SQL query using any tool of your choice you should get an error like the following:

> Unknown column '123b' in 'where clause'

This is because `123b` cannot be an integer as it contains a letter, and isn't a string as it has no string delimiters.

> Note that MySQL can still interpret strings without delimiters like hexadecimal values. For example, `0x31323362` is a valid string value for `123b` and does not need quotes around it.

Comment: yes I did try that earlier (int) we need to cast this string